# How to set request propert while making http connection?

Tags: java, http

i am making http connection using

```
URL urlToConnect = new URL ("http://www.xyz.com");
HttpURLConnection connection = ( HttpURLConnection )  urlToConnect.openConnection();
```

I need to set the following property ,i am doing it like

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("user-agent", USER_AGENT);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
connection.setRequestProperty("http_code", "200");
connection.setRequestProperty("USERNAME", "test");
connection.setRequestProperty("PASSWORD", "test");
```

Is it the right way to set all these data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are doing is perfect.

Comment: But i am getting response 400 always from the server,i also want to know how to set username and password while making connection ? i am using setrequestproperty method.

Comment: and the connection uses https,so i am setting port and host also

Comment: If the connection is https, then your URL is wrong, it says "http".  Setting host and port on the URL is fine.  Do your username and password come in on a query string? like:

    http://www.xyz.dom?user=username&password=password

If so, then the request property is not what you want. I think you just put the query string in the URL just like I do it.

Comment: no username and pwd does not come with url it has to be set in request ,ya i am using https only

Comment: Maybe you can run wireshark to capture what the request actually is?  And you can post that (changing things as required for security)  A 400 indicates something is really messed up which is not usual when making an HTTP request.

Comment: Oh, and are you sure they are expecting an HTTP POST?  Perhaps they are expecting an HTTP GET instead.  If they do want a post, are you actually sending the data (calling getOutputStream() and writing something to the request?)